Type check for optional property when the property is undefined
I'm trying to perform a type check on an optional property to determine whether it is undefined when no value is assigned. My goal is to dynamically check if an optional property has been set or not, since I want to handle cases where the property is intentionally left out.
type A = {
  aa?: string
}

const a:A = {}

const { aa } = a

type B = typeof aa extends undefined ? true : false // false

Since I didn’t assign a value to aa, I expected typeof aa to be undefined, and B to be true. However, the result is false.
How can I check the type dynamically when no value is assigned?

If you’re going to annotate a as type A<string> then you’re throwing away that information. Why annotate at all? What purpose does that serve? Maybe the example needs more motivation? Right now I don’t know why A is generic (you’re not demonstrating anything that uses such flexibility) and I’m not sure why you want annotations like this. Please [edit] to clarify.

I don't believe TS can know if a property has been omitted v being undefined, but JS certainly knows. https://tsplay.dev/WGQRMN

Can you change A to be a union as shown in this playground link? Then you'll get assignment narrowing and things behave as you want. Otherwise it's either not possible (since assignment narrowing doesn't work on single object types) or I don't understand what you want. Let me know how you want to proceed.

@jcalz the union differs from the original type with a very difference: aa?: undefined | aa: string !== aa?: string. i guess the question has no answer since ts cannot infer undefined here

When you annotate a variable with a non-union type like A:
const a: A = {}

you are throwing away any information TypeScript might have had about the initializing value {}. All TypeScript knows about a is that its type is A, and thus the aa property is of type string | undefined. And since (string | undefined) extends undefined is false, you get the behavior you're seeing:
const { aa } = a;
type B = typeof aa extends undefined ? true : false // false

In other words, TypeScript does not narrow a from A to something else upon that assignment.  If you could make A a union like
type A = { aa: string } | { aa?: undefined }

then TypeScript will perform assignment narrowing at
const a: A = {}

which can be seen by observing a afterwards:
const { aa } = a;
//             ^? const a: { aa?: undefined; }

And thus aa is of type undefined as desired.
const a: A = {}
const { aa } = a
type B = typeof aa extends undefined ? true : false // true


Of course {aa?: string} and {aa: string} | {aa?: undefined} aren't identical to each other. They behave mostly the same if you're just reading from the variable, but when setting the aa property you can't switch from one union member to the other:
let a: A = {}; // okay either way
a.aa = "abc"; // not okay with union type
a = { aa: "abc" }; // okay either way
delete a.aa; // not okay with union type

So if you can't make that change then you're kind of stuck. There is a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#16976 to implement non-union assignment narrowing, but it's not part of the language now and I wouldn't expect to see it anytime soon.
Playground link to code
